# Change active build target xcode 4

Tags: compilation, xcode4

I am not able to run the `TestXcodeColors.app` [in this project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors)

[image]

Comment: Downvoter, what makes this not a great question?

Comment: Title is perfect, maybe body needs a bit more explanation like 'when I clean or build the project, it builds XCodeColors, and I want it to build TestXCodeColors.app instead..

Comment: Title is good, this is exactly what I was looking for, switching between a full version and a lite version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Product** / **Edit Scheme...**

[image: edit scheme]

Choose the "Scheme" aka "Target to build" in the drop down that says "Scheme" and hit "OK"